# SQL Matrix query

Tags: sql, matrix, count, subquery

I am having trouble trying to return a number of events per month.

I have one table, with 3 columns; callback, followup, service. What I am trying to do is return the number of each times each one of these events occurred per month for an account.

I have attempted to use a subquery:

```
Select...<columns>...
(
    select 
    COUNT(eventname)
    from 
    tworkorderevent 
    group by eventname
    having 
    eventname = 'Follow up'
)FollowUps,
from <tablename>
where...
group by ...
```

but this is only returning the total number of the event, rather than the number per account per month.

Any suggestions or requests for clarity are gladly appreciated and received. Thank you.

Comment: your subquery should be: select eventname, COUNT(eventname)

Comment: Thank you so much, @StaticVoid. I've been circling around with this statement, but get an error indicating only one expression can be specified in the select list.

Comment: I've been able to make some progress; your suggestion gave me an idea. I added datepart() function to  the select and group by and  moved the subquery to a join statement and now I am not returning any errors :) Still not getting results as expected, but I presume this is because I am not using the correct joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this then:

```
Select a.account_id, b.follow_up_count, c.callback_count, d.service_count
From tworkorderevent a
Left Outer Join
(
    select account_id, COUNT(eventname) as follow_up_count
    from tworkorderevent
    where eventname like 'Follow up'
    group by account_id
)b On a.account_id = b.account_id
Left Outer Join
(
    select account_id, COUNT(eventname) as callback_count
    from tworkorderevent
    where eventname like 'Callback'
    group by account_id
)c On a.account_id = c.account_id
Left Outer Join
(
    select account_id, COUNT(eventname) as service_count
    from tworkorderevent
    where eventname like 'Service'
    group by account_id
)d On a.account_id = d.account_id
```

Just replace the "account_id" references with whatever your primary key is, and ensure that the values for each "Where" statement are correct.

Comment: Yup! That got it! Thanks a million @StaticVoid